# Turbo Pascal 5.5 "Error 3: Unknown Identifier" with ASM keyword

Tags: pascal, turbo-pascal

I downloaded TP 5.5 and installed it in my Virtual Machine which is running FreeDOS.

I tried this short code:

```
Program test;

begin
asm
   mov ax, ax
end;
end.
```

Turbo Pascal says: "Error 3: Unknown Identifier."

I can use the keyword inline works BUT I can't use mnemonics with it and my goal is just to learn some assembly while being in Real Mode so I can't go to Delphi and use mnemonics there.

Comment: Evidently, symbolic inline assembler hadn't yet been added to the language at the time when version 5.5 was released.

Comment: Perhaps it's using at&t syntax?  Have you tried `mov %ax, %ax`?

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error It may be it but I've seen a Turbo Pascal code with mnemonics.

Comment: @David Wohlerd It's not that because even if I remove that line it says that it doesn't know what "asm" means.

Comment: @user250327: It was indeed supported in some versions of Turbo Pascal but apparently not the one you have.

Answer (score 2):

Integrated "basm" assembler was a TP 6.0 feature indeed. 5.5 is the newest that is free though.

Better use Free Pascal.